# Issues while moving from Azure to Google Cloud Service

Tags: azure, google-app-engine, go

Based on my searches, I created a Project and deployed a couple of services following that link: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-app-engine-go/index.html?index=..%2F..index#0

After a lot of struggle I could deploy but now I am not even sure that an app is really running somewhere as I have no log at all (I didn’t find any at least, just one telling `2019-10-29T21:56:21.890Z App Engine UpdateService users-service john.doe@email.com .........`), I haven’t find any metrics, and I can’t reach my API..

My API currently defines 2 ports (gRPC & REST), so I tried to ping the given address, adding port and without it, but no success as I can’t reach my service..

I am literally stuck right now, I tried a couple of log libraries regarding Google Cloud documentation but nothing seems to work for me, everything stays empty.

```
- "google.golang.org/appengine/log"
- "cloud.google.com/go/logging"
- "log"
```

Back to work this morning, after an hour I tried to re deploy my service and I got my 3 first logs

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    ...
)

func main() {


    log.Print("Users Service")
    log.Println("Users Service")
    log.Printf("Users Service")

    log.Fatal("Heyyyyyyy")

//...
```

I edited my code, I added a print a bit later on in my main and re deploy. Now I don't have the first logs anymore.. It seems like I can log sometimes, but then, it stops working for a while and come back. Any idea?

I tried to update my print function, still no success:

```
// appengineLog is actually the official package but I renamed it to use both "log" and "appengine/log"
// import appengineLog "google.golang.org/appengine/log"

func print(v string) {
    log.Print(v)
    log.Println(v)
    log.Printf("%s", v)
    ctx, _ := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 2*time.Second)
    appengineLog.Infof(ctx, "%s", v)
    appengineLog.Debugf(ctx, "%s", v)
    appengineLog.Errorf(ctx, "%s", v)
    appengineLog.Warningf(ctx, "%s", v)
    appengineLog.Criticalf(ctx, "%s", v)
}

func main() {
    print("test")
    // ...
}
```

The weird point is that I am getting `2019-10-29T21:56:21.890Z App Engine UpdateService users-service john.doe@email.com .........` messages for each deploy, so it means (to me) that my service got deployed so it should get started and print. The print is at the first line of my main so..

## EDIT

As I am moving from Monolith to Microservices, I opted for Google Compute Engine which seems more appropriate for such deployment :)

Comment: Sorry, but I don't really understand your question. Do you have a Go application on Google Cloud Platform and you want to call its API or do you have an API outside of Google Cloud and you want to call it from newly created Go App engine?

Comment: Hey ! My goal would be to rewrite my API in go (done) and publish it to google cloud platform. I newly created my app engine and tried gcloud app deploy . I am now looking to reach my API but no success.. so I look for anything that can help me to monitor or debug what is happening (such as logs?)

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud offers many ways to debug and monitor your application such as [Stackdriver logging](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/quickstart-sdk) where you monitor, debug and filter  the activity of your app. [You can view logs and even export them](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/overview). Google Cloud also offers [Stackdriver monitoring](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/docs/how-to) to make uptime checks of your system, alerting policies, chart for any metrics with metric explorer. add to that you can even create your own custom metrics yo use in Stackdriver monitoring.

Comment: Hey ! Thanks for your answer. As mentioned in my Edit 1, I am already looking at these panel to monitor, but I don't get logs. It just appears sometimes when I deploy my app but that's it

Comment: please, keep monitoring and get back to me tomorrow. I will help you further with this. if this keep persisting, you open a support ticket "https://cloud.google.com/support/" and they will give you more details on the issue.

Comment: I am already trying to monitor since 2 days.. I tried to contact the support so I am waiting for them to come back to me. In the meantime, I will keep digging..

Comment: please, let me know if they update you on something. I'm interested in this issue.

Comment: Will do ! And I am going to edit my question as well